# AngularJS: multiple $rootScope.$watch functions failing in app.js

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the following function in app.js to conditionally change dom elements in case of back/forward browser buttons/keyboard:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
        $rootScope.$watch(function() {
            if ( !$location.path().match(/\/$/) ) {
                //dom changes
            }
        },
        true);
    });
```

I would like to add another conditional statement to do something else:

```
if ( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/) ) {
    //other stuff
}
```

but no matter where I try to insert it, it breaks the script. How can I chain this in to not conflict with previous statement?

edit: just to clarify, it's not intended to modify first if statement.

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding sooner. The problem turned out to be a browser malfunction (which occasionally happens on my old mac G5 running TenFourFox, a ppc-optimized fork of Firefox). After restarting the browser, everything was good.